# How to add shred to KDE context menu for safe deletion of file/folder?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kde-plasma, shred

How to add the [shred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)) utility to the context menu in Dolphin (Linux Mint 18 KDE) for removing files and **folders**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create file `shred.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/allfiles;
Actions=Shred
#X-KDE-Submenu=Shred

[Desktop Action Shred]
Name=Safe Remove
Name[ru]=Удалить навсегда
Icon=trash-empty
Exec=shred -u -f -z -n3 %u
```

2. Create file `shred_folder.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=inode/directory;
Actions=Shred
#X-KDE-Submenu=Shred

[Desktop Action Shred]
Name=Safe Folder Remove
Name[ru]=Удалить папку навсегда
Icon=trash-empty
Exec=find %u -type f -exec shred -u -f -z -n3 {} \;
#Exec=find %u -type f -exec notify-send {} '' \;
```

3. Put these files here: `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/` ([how to find this path?](https://askubuntu.com/a/719757))
4. Reboot (or restart session)

**Result:**

[image: result]

Additional info:

1. `MimeType` for files is `all/allfiles`, for folders it's `inode/directory`
2. Used shred options:

```
-u  - After shredding a file, deallocate it (if possible) and then remove it.
-f  - Change permissions to allow writing if necessary.
-z  - Add a final overwrite with zeros to hide shredding.
-n3 - Use 3 passes of overwriting.
%u  - The file path for removing.
```

3. Specifics for removing a folder with shred: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27029/330017
4. Here's more on creating context menu entries: [KDE documentation](https://develop.kde.org/docs/dolphin/service-menus/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly changed version that implements a confirmation dialog and a more appropriate icon (imho)

- Files

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/allfiles;
Actions=Shred
#X-KDE-Submenu=Shred

[Desktop Action Shred]
Name=Safe Remove
Icon=edit-delete-shred
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'kdialog --title "Safe Delete" --warningcontinuecancel "Safe Delete: Are you sure?" && shred -u -f -z -n3 %u'
```

- Directories

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=inode/directory;
Actions=Shred
#X-KDE-Submenu=Shred

[Desktop Action Shred]
Name=Safe Folder Remove
Icon=edit-delete-shred
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'kdialog --title "Safe Delete" --warningcontinuecancel "Safe Delete: Are you sure?" && find %u -type f -exec shred -u -f -z -n3 {} \; && rmdir %u'
```